# 2 3rd party C and c++ library have same class and struct name as Object so I am getting this reference to 'Object' is ambiguous error

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile

I have this situation, I am using 2 3rd party libraries written in C and C++, both of them have defined a struct and a class respectively with the same name. So when I am building they are complaining about - reference to 'Object' is ambiguous.

I have 2 header files from the 2 of these libraries which have a struct and class with same name and I include both of them in my project.

Any idea how can I overcome this ?

Comment: It sounds like one of them is in a namespace or something (otherwise you would get a `redefiniton of Object` error), so you should be able to just use fully qualified name (`namespace::Object`) and/or remove the `using namespace ???` line from your file.

Comment: But the class object is used internally in the library without any namespace prefix :/

Comment: Well that's as much as I can guess without seeing some code that demonstrates the problem or at least the exact error message.

Comment: @DavidBrown : I asked my peers if I can change the library and the answer was yes, so just added the namespace to it and it solves that problem, thank you :)

Comment: David - Post your comment as a solution and bana mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the conflicting class definitions in different namespaces.